# Can I have navigation properties based on certain fields (not primary keys!, unique or foreign keys)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, navigation-properties

Say we have 2 tables

```
public class Table1
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ID2 { get; set; }

    public int ID3 { get; set; }
}

public class Table2
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ID2 { get; set; }

    public int ID3 { get; set; }
}
```

Column ID is primary key in Table1 and in Table2, and that's it!

Now, I want to create a relationship ( not in the database!); I just want to lie to  EntityFramework that there is a relationship between these 2 tables.

So, I want ID2 from Table2 to be foreign key and reference **not column ID** from **Table1**, but **column ID2**.

Is that possible?

**EDIT2**

I know is possible something like

```
public class Table2
{
    //...

    public int ID2 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID2")]
    public Table1 Table1 { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

and

```
public class Table1
{

    //...

    public virtual ICollection<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

I successfully expanded all Table2 rows for a certain Table1 row.

The join of the sql will be like: Table1.**ID** = Table2.ID2;
I need it to be like Table1.**ID2** = Table2.ID2

Comment: This does not make any sense to me. What for you want to "lie" to ef and have such a fake relationship?

Comment: because of the model I deal with... There is a table where these fake relationships are provided and this table often changes. So with a console application I generate the model anytime this table changes. Read edit2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up creating 2 views for the A table and mapping those views to EF Entities. First view has ID as primary key, second view has ID2 as primary key. Obviously, second view was the one used to expand all Table2 rows.